get a boolean key=value with a default value, and a numeric key=value to work together in tikz
I am interested in learning pgfkeys, and using them for key=value options in custom tikz commands. I am exploring the section 87 in the tikz doc, but it will take me some time to go through.
I can get a boolean key=value with a default value, and a numeric key=value to work separately, but not together.
Here is some code that I have that works: (credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725177/319072)
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifdrawAxes
\pgfqkeys{/drawaxes}{show axes/.is if=drawAxes}
\newcommand{\Grid}[2][]{%
    \pgfqkeys{/drawaxes}{#1}%
    \draw (#2) circle[radius=1];
    \ifdrawAxes
      \draw[->] (#2) -- ++(1,0);
      \draw[->] (#2) -- ++(0,1);
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Grid[]{1,3}
    \Grid[show axes] {0,0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is some other code that I have that works: (Credit: AI)
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /grid/.is family, /grid,
  default/.style = {size=1},
  size/.store in = \grid@size,
}

\newcommand{\Grid}[3][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/grid, default, #1}%
    \draw (#2) grid ($\grid@size*(#3)$);
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Grid[size=2]{1,3}{2,6}
    \Grid[]{0,0}{2,1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


However, when I put them together, it raises a bunch of errors:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{
  /grid/.is family, /grid,
  default/.style = {size=1},
  size/.store in = \grid@size,
}

\newif\ifdrawAxes
\pgfqkeys{/drawaxes}{show axes/.is if=drawAxes}


\newcommand{\Grid}[3][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/grid, default, #1}%
    \pgfqkeys{/drawaxes}{#2}%
    \draw (0,0) grid ($\grid@size*(#3)$);z
    \ifdrawAxes
      \draw[->] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
      \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-1);
    \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Grid[size=3, show axes]{1,3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


@cfr I don't think pgf or TikZ define /grid, so this should be fine.

@Skillmon if you say so ;). I still think it is a bad idea to use a key path which matches the name of a default pattern, even if it is protected by a top level patterns (which I guess is what you mean).

@cfr thank you for your comment. I chose \Grid for sakeof an MWE, in my actual document it is more unique :-)

@Jasper the problem is not the macro name, \newcommand will check that it doesn't clash. The problem is that \tikzset, \pgfkeys, etc. doesn't guarantee new keys if used as you do, and you chose a very generic path /grid which might clash (it doesn't with core pgf and TikZ, but I didn't check every library and released package there is)..

@Skillmon Ahh, I see. Thank you

@Jasper that's also the reason why the MWE in my answer uses /jasper as the base path.

You're changing the key-path for the optional argument to /grid and then try to set show axes, so the searched key is /grid/show axes, which you didn't define, you defined /drawaxes/show axes. Also you define your \Grid macro to take three arguments, and the second are options for the /drawaxes group. So using your definition the following works: \Grid[size=3]{show axes}{1,3}
However, you could also define both key groups in the same path if they don't clash and use a single optional argument for your keys:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifdrawAxes
\pgfqkeys{/jasper}
  {
    .is family
    ,size/.store in = \grid@size
    ,show axes/.is if = drawAxes
    ,default/.style = {size=1}
  }

\newcommand{\Grid}[2][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/jasper}{default,#1}%
  \draw (0,0) grid ($\grid@size*(#2)$);%
  \ifdrawAxes
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-1);
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Grid[size=3, show axes]{1,3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

